# android 3 EditText в RecyclerVIew

Tags: android, recyclerview, edittext

Хочу реализовать, чтобы в RecyclerView было 3 Edittext, но приложение выдает ошибку, подскажите, что я делаю не так, весь код снизу.

```
public class EditModel {

        private String editTextValue1, editTextValue2, editTextValue3;

        public String getEditTextValue1() {
            return editTextValue1;
        }
        public String getEditTextValue2() {
            return editTextValue2;
        }
        public String getEditTextValue3() {
            return editTextValue3;
        }

        public void setEditTextValue1(String editTextValue1) {
            this.editTextValue1 = editTextValue1;
        }
        public void setEditTextValue2(String editTextValue2) {
            this.editTextValue2 = editTextValue2;
        }
        public void setEditTextValue3(String editTextValue3) {
            this.editTextValue3 = editTextValue3;
        }
    }

    public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        public static ArrayList<EditModel> editModelArrayList;


        public CustomAdapter( ArrayList<EditModel> editModelArrayList){


            this.editModelArrayList = editModelArrayList;
        }

        @Override
        public CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rec_numbet_item, parent, false);
            MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


            holder.editText1.setText(editModelArrayList.get(position).getEditTextValue1());
            holder.editText2.setText(editModelArrayList.get(position).getEditTextValue2());
            holder.editText3.setText(editModelArrayList.get(position).getEditTextValue3());
            Log.d("print","yes");

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return editModelArrayList.size();
        }

        class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            protected EditText editText1, editText2, editText3;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                editText1 = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                editText2 = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                editText3 = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText3);

                editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                        editModelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setEditTextValue1(editText1.getText().toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                    }
                });
                editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                        editModelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setEditTextValue2(editText2.getText().toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                    }
                });
                editText3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                        editModelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setEditTextValue3(editText3.getText().toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                    }
                });

            }

        }
    }



    public class ActivityChoose extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private CustomAdapter mAdapter;
    public ArrayList<EditModel> mDataSet;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rec_numbet_item);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        mDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6 ; i ++) {
            EditModel entry = new EditModel();
            mDataSet.add(entry);
        }

        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mDataSet);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.sapsan.autonumber, PID: 23644
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sapsan.autonumber/com.sapsan.autonumber.ActivityChoose}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                  at com.sapsan.autonumber.ActivityChoose.onCreate(ActivityChoose.java:39)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: какую ошибку и на какой строке?

Comment: добавил сообщ. об ошибке

Comment: у вас в разметке нет `R.id.recycler`. Программа его не находит, `RecyclerView = null`, отсюда NPE

Comment: R.id.recycler либо нет, либо это id не RecyclerView

Comment: Покажите XML-разметку там где ресайклер